# Any security reason not to use `root` user for git remote operations?

Tags: linux, security, git

I've got some configs (`docker-compose` related files) which I like to store them via `git` on a private `github` repo.
The configs are owned by root.
Is there any reason to change the ownership of the files to do the `git push` and `git pull` and via another user other than `root`?

Answer (score 6):

There's *no reason* to use git as root. There is no functionality in git that requires superuser privileges.

You should *only* use superuser privileges when ***required***. Even though the risk of a vulnerability that may be exploitable in this scenario is low, there's no gains by taking this risk, and habits is good defence.

Only run things as `root` when you *need* to.